# Инструкция по tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.x, tkinter

Хочу начать пользоваться tkinter, но не мог найти учебник.

Comment: ссылки из ответов добавлены в описание метки [tag:tkinter]. там их и стоит править/добавлять/искать.

Answer (score 2):

Первая же ссылка в гугле по запросу "tkinter":

https://ru.wikiversity.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B5_Tkinter_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0_Python

Там всё очень подробно расписано.

Answer (score 2):

[WIKI курс](https://ru.wikiversity.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B5_Tkinter_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0_Python)
[Доки](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html)
[Скачать в pdf](http://kabinet-vplaksina.narod.ru/olderfiles/5/Modul_tkinter.pdf)

Tkinter не самый лучший выбор если честно.

Comment: Да норамальный Tkinter. Выглядит не хуже Qt, если есть хоть немного фантазии. К тому же простой, как три копейки.

Comment: Возможно, не буду спорить.

Comment: Для простых интерфейсов лучше ткинтера вряд ли что-то можно найти. Особенно если человек настолько начинающий, что гуглом пользоваться не умеет.